# How to execute and debug an acrobat reader plugin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, acrobat

I have downloaded the acrobat reader Xi sdk and I'm trying to run the sample BatesNumbering,  ,in visual studio but I'm getting errors but building works fine. I am getting the error Unable to start program. I have read the documentation but not all of it and I tried looking on the net. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still up to date:
I'm just starting with Adobe Reader/Acrobat development, but when I get it right you tried to start the plugin in visual studio.

I think you have to specify Acrobat as the output program, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Maybe this can help:
[Debugging - Acrobat SDK](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/11/Acrobat11_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat11_HTMLHelp&file=Plugins_CreatingSimplePlug.34.12.html)